# How to save a file using NSURLSessionDownloadTask and AFNetworking 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm creating a download task as indicated in the AFNetworking docs (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-a-download-task).

When the NSURLSessionDownloadTask reached the block `completionHandler` the error is null, so there's no error. Also, the `filePath` returns a valid `NSURL`, such as `/var/mobile/Applications/id-of-the-app/Documents/section/section13.png`.

The problem is that it's not saving the file in the specified folder (the folder exists, and the file to be downloaded too).

Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl]];

    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section%@.%@", section.sectionId, [request.URL pathExtension]];

    NSURL *saveUrl = [FilesManager urlForResourceType:ResourceTypeSection andFilename:filename];


    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                     progress:nil
                                                                  destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
    {
        return saveUrl;
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"path - %@", filePath);
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"we're good");
        }
    }];

    [downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: Have you tried saving it anywhere else?

Comment: Yes I did (all in Documents, though)

Comment: Sorry to necro this but I'm encountering the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution? I've tried deleting the target file if it already exists, and changing the url session to ephemeral, but still the downloaded file only appears sometimes (yet progress always reaches 1.0 and in Charles I can see the whole image data coming down the pipe).

Comment: Not long after my comment I discovered the cause was related to the iOS Simulator. Using my real iPad for testing did not exhibit the same issue.